# Symmetries of a Hexagon

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having trouble with the following problem.

Let $D_{12} = <a,b:a^6=b^2=e, ba=a^5b>$, the dihedral group of order 12, describe the symmetries of a regular hexagon. $a$ denotes a rotation about the center by 60 degrees, and $b$ denotes a reflection across a diagonal connecting a pair of opposite vertices.

I need to find the centralizers $C_{D_{12}}(a)$, $C_{D_{12}}(b)$, as well as the center $Z(D_{12})$.

Clearly, each element of $D_{12}$ can be written in the form $a^ib^j$, with $0\leq i\leq5$, and $0\leq j\leq1$. To find the centralizers, I think I need to use the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, but I'm not sure how to find the center.

Answer (score 1):

Centralizer of rotation is all rotations, centralizer of reflection is itself and the identity element. Centralizer of $G$ is identity and rotation by $\pi$.